# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null even though it is not null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete anything that might be on a text field. These text fields have different id's and the id needs getting generated from a count. So i know that the id has been created and it exsists. Here is my js code.

```
    var score= 2;
    function hideNewDiv(){

        document.getElementById('showAnotherDiv').style.display='inline';
        score--;
        document.getElementById("Feedback_"+score+"_score").value = "";
        document.getElementById('newSF' + score).style.display='none';

        if (score== 2){
            document.getElementById('hideAnotherDiv').style.display='none';
        }
    }
```

when it gets to setting the value to "" i get the error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you feel about jQuery, because it was written to support this functionality (which is very complex) across different browsers? Do you only need this working in a specific browser? And also, please include some of the html so we can see the divs that you are referencing.

Comment: `if (score== 2){}` will never trigger since you decrement `score` before that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. My problem was not with Javascript, the problem was behind my HTML. I had not specified an id. i forgot i only had a name specified. common rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This implies there is no element with ID `"Feedback_"+score+"_score"`. `score` starts at 2, but you decrement it each time you run your function, so it becomes `1`, then `0`, then `-1`, and so on, depending on how many times you call it. You need to validate the value of `score` before trying to access an element using it.